# How to detect 204 No Content from Android Volley Request

Tags: android, android-volley, http-status-code-204

When i request to my api api returns 204 - No Content. But volley does not recognise that and give TimeOutError.

How can i handle this ?

Comment: Check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21968409/1281775

Answer (score 1):

When you setup a new volley request :

```
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
        new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
        // act upon a valid response
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        // Handle error
        }
    });
```

Notice that you pass a `Response.ErrorListener`. When error occurs, such as for instance 204, the `onErrorResponse(VolleyError)` callback is called with the `VolleyError` instance - error with appropriate information about the error passed to it.

So in this callback you should inspect for the error and take appropriate action.

```
new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            if(error instanceof TimeoutError){
             // Take action when timeout happens
            }
        }
    }
```

NOTE : When timeout happens, the `VolleyError` instance is in fact an instance of `TimeoutError` a subclass of `VolleyError`. Hence we check if the error caused is timeout using `instanceof`

The list of VolleyError sub classes are available here : http://afzaln.com/volley/com/android/volley/VolleyError.html

The example given is for `StringRequest` type but the technique is the same for other `VolleyObjectRequest` types.

Comment: First of all thanks for well-defined answer. I currently handle like this but this metodoly is wrong, i think. Because if it really occurs timeot connection, i will miss it. This logic makes this;

timeout exception -> no content
no content -> no content

Comment: Oh, I understand now. `Volley` misinterprets 204 for `TimeoutError`. Silly me! I completely misunderstood it.

Comment: Possible duplicate. Check [this out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27392813/android-volley-library-not-working-with-204-and-empty-body-response)